# reading csv file in C

Tags: c

please help me!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m57Yf.jpg)

my text file is here. I want to read all of them but i can take half of it. I dont know why..

Can you check my code? thnx a lot.

```
FILE *fp;
char temp[10][250];
int i,j;
if((fp=fopen("init.txt","r"))==NULL)
{
    printf("Reading Error!!");
}
fscanf(fp,"%d\n%d,%d", &botanist->water_bootle_size, &forest->height, &forest->width);
printf("%d %d %d ",botanist->water_bootle_size, forest->height, forest->width);
for(i=0;i<forest->height;i++)
{
    fgets(temp[i],forest->width*2+1,fp);
}
for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
{
    printf("%s",temp[j]);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: 1) why the second `fp = fopen("init.cvs","r");`  ? 2) Please check the return value from `fscanf`

Answer (score 2):

Your test is misparenthesized. It should read:

```
if ((fp = fopen("init.csv", "r")) == NULL)
```

The second call `fp = fopen("init.cvs","r");` is redundant and should be removed.

Also `fscanf()` is not a very good tool to parse CSV files:

- if the file contains quoted strings with commas, scanning for `,` may have incorrect behavior.
- it cannot handle empty fields
- parsing errors are very difficult to recover from.

Assuming the file has simple contents, you should parse the first line separately to handle the columns numbers and change the `fscanf()` for this way:

```
if (fscanf(fp,"%d,%d,%d,%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,],%49[^,]", 
       &water, &x, &y, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10) == 13) {
    /* 13 fields correctly parsed */
}
```

Comment: thnx for answer, which function do you suggest to parse csv files? and what does %49 mean in this code?  thnx again..

Comment: If your CSV file is simple enough, `fscanf` can do the job, otherwise you way need to write a parser by hand. `%49[^,]` means store 1 to 49 bytes  different from `,` into the array.

Comment: 50
10,1
#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#,#
B, , , ,#,#, , , ,#
#, ,#, , , , ,#, ,#
#, ,#,#,#,#, ,#, ,#
#, ,#, , , , ,#,#,#
#, ,#, ,#, , , , ,#
#, ,#, ,#,#,#,#,#,#
#, ,#, , , , , , ,#
#, ,#,#,#,#, ,#, ,#
#, , , , ,#,F,#,#,#

my file includes those.. i can read 50 10 10 and the first line starting with #  by fscanf("%d %d, %d %s") but i cant reach the rest of it..

 if you cant see, there are 12 rows.

Comment: @DorukCanBaşıbüyük: if this is a line from your CSV file, it cannot be parsed with `fscanf()` because it contains empty fields. `%[^,]` requires at least one character different from `,` to succeed.  Similarly, `strtok()` cannot be used in a hand coded parser because it would consider any sequence of `,` to be a single separator.

Answer (score 0):

Your fopen line should read (look at the difference: first assignment, then the check for its result).

```
if (NULL == (fp = fopen("init.csv","r"))){
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code block

```
if((fp = fopen("init.csv","r")==NULL)) {
}
```

is wrong as first `fopen("init.csv","r")==NULL)` evaluated & if file is present  it gives `0` (comparison operator) & then `fp = 0` evaluated which hopefully not your intention.

```
if( (fp = fopen("init.csv","r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr," some messagee ");
        return 0;
}
else {
        printf("it works");
}
//fp = fopen("init.cvs","r"); /* why open again */
fscanf(); /* check the return value */
```